# CUDA-like workflow for OpenCL

Tags: compilation, workflow, opencl, static-linking

The typical example workflow for OpenCL programming seems to be focused on source code within strings, passed to the JIT compiler, then finally enqueued (with a specific kernel name); and the compilation results can be cached - but that's left for you the programmer to take care of.

In CUDA, the code is compiled in a non-JIT way to object files (alongside host-side code, but forget about that for a second), and then one just refers to device-side functions in the context of an enqueue or arguments etc.

Now, I'd like to have the second kind of workflow, but with OpenCL sources. That is, suppose I have some C host-side code `my_app.c`, and some OpenCL kernel code in a separate file, `my_kernel.cl` (which for the purpose of discussion is self-contained). I would like to be able to run a magic command on `my_kernel.cl`, get a `my_kernel.whatever`, link or faux-link that together with `my_app.o`, and get a binary. Now, in `my_app.c` I want to be able to somehow to refer to the kernel, even if it's not an extern symbol, as compiled OpenCL program (or program + kernel name) - and not get compilation errors.

Is this supported somehow? With nVIDIA's ICD or with one of the other ICDs? If not, is at least *some* of this supported, say, the magic kernel compiler + generation of an extra header or source stub to use in compiling `my_app.c`?

Answer (score 3):

Look into **SYCL**, it offers single-source C++ OpenCL. However, not yet available on every platform.

https://www.khronos.org/sycl

Comment: Isn't that kind of an understatement? It seems to require not-yet-standard C++ functionality (C++17 material?) Also, that's a specification/standard; are there any conforming SYCL implementations?

Comment: Yes, perhaps an understatement; I don't use SYCL so I wasn't sure of its availability.

Comment: Then maybe in 3 years or so I can accept this answer :-) You got my +1 though.

Answer (score 1):

There is already ongoing effort that enables CUDA-like workflow in TensorFlow, and it uses SYCL 1.2 - it is actively up-streamed.

Similarly to CUDA, SYCL's approach needs the following steps:

- device registration via device factory ( device is called SYCL )  - done here: https://github.com/lukeiwanski/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/core/common_runtime/sycl
- operation registration for above device. In order to create / port operation you can either:

  - re-use Eigen's code since Tensor module has SYCL back-end ( look here: https://github.com/lukeiwanski/tensorflow/blob/opencl/adjustcontrastv2/tensorflow/core/kernels/adjust_contrast_op.cc#L416 - we just partially specialize operation for SYCL device and calling the already implemented functor https://github.com/lukeiwanski/tensorflow/blob/opencl/adjustcontrastv2/tensorflow/core/kernels/adjust_contrast_op.h#L91;
  - write SYCL code - it has been done for FillPhiloxRandom - see https://github.com/lukeiwanski/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/random_op.cc#L685

    - SYCL kernel uses modern C++
    - you can use OpenCL interoperability -  thanks to which you can write pure OpenCL C kernel code! - I think this bit is most relevant to you

The workflow is a bit different as you do not have to do an explicit instantiation of the functor templates as CUDA does https://github.com/lukeiwanski/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/adjust_contrast_op_gpu.cu.cc or any `.cu.cc` file  ( in fact you do not have to add any new files - avoids mess with the build system )

As well as this thing: https://github.com/lukeiwanski/tensorflow/issues/89;

TL;DR - CUDA can create "persistent" pointers, OpenCL needs to go through Buffers and Accessors.

Codeplay's SYCL compiler ( ComputeCpp ) at the moment requires OpenCL 1.2 with SPIR extension - these are Intel CPU, Intel GPU ( Beignet work in progress ), AMD GPU ( although older drivers ) - additional platforms are coming!

Setup instructions can be found here: https://www.codeplay.com/portal/03-30-17-setting-up-tensorflow-with-opencl-using-sycl

Our effort can be tracked in my fork of TensorFlow:  https://github.com/lukeiwanski/tensorflow ( branch dev/eigen_mehdi )

Eigen used is: https://bitbucket.org/mehdi_goli/opencl ( branch default )

We are getting there! Contributions are welcome! :)